# What is this person doing?

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone know what type of operation this wallet below is doing? And how is she racking up so many WSOL?

wallet: https://solscan.io/account/DCAKxnquJnRYHDqp3qzyBS4qztddcbEQsGv68z6boUwr#splTransfers

Comment: It is the address of the Jupiter DCA Bot.

Comment: Like this? Not a person? What does this DCA bot do? Can you explain better please?

Comment: Using DCA bot, you can purchase a token using a premeditated strategy over a number of days rather than a single order (as you do in a market or limit order). See: https://jup.ag/dca to learn more.

Comment: But it doesn't seem like this guy is running a DCA at all. Have you seen the pattern of his transactions? Some transactions he exchanges SOL for a token, and in the next second the token for SOL again, and leaves with a profit.. This doesn't seem like DCA to me

Comment: This isn't a question for dev Q&A, I will be closing this question

Answer (score 0):

i saw many people giving you wrong answers.

What's happening in reality is that this guy is frontrunning people.
It's an MEV BOT

Example below :

[image: MEV]

Comment: Do you think he is a validator? Or did he just learn to do something in a way we don't yet know?